# A turn request should not include candidates for stun

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I have created Co-Turn server with Time-Limited Credentials Mechanism.
I have setup that credential should expire after 5 minutes.

Verified that with -
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

I have generated the username and password and tested in this tool, result is showing STUN (server reflexive candidate) and relay -

**It is showing server reflexive or stun candidate and relay candidate.**

Then after expiring the credentials I have tried again to gather candidates.

**It is showing server reflexive or stun candidate.**

Here, in the gather candidates it should not give the candidates if credentials already expire.

So, why server reflexive or stun candidate is still coming?

A turn request should not include candidates for stun.

Can anyone help on this this , how to resolve this issue?

Or Can we also use the credentials for stun server?

Any inputs in this regard would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone please help on this issue, need some quick support .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable STUN candidates, try setting `no-stun` option in co-turn config, otherwise setting `secure-stun` option should authenticate STUN requests too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added secure-stun in co-turn config, in this case I have tried stun with or without credentials but not able get ice candidates.
In case of turn, it is giving relay but it should come with server reflexive or stun candidate also.

In case of no-stun it enables turn only, so, when i am trying make RTCpeerconnection  with TURN at both end client side and server side , its not able to make connection.

Answer (score 0):

STUN as a protocol is not authenticated (since it is cheap) so it does not matter that your credentials expired, the srflx candidate will still be gathered.